# Why does fgetc not stop at eof

Tags: c, file

Assume I have `input.txt` which contains "123456789". I am trying to write odd numbers to `odd.txt` and even numbers to `even.txt` by using `fputc` and `fgetc`. I don't have any problem with `even.txt` but `odd.txt` contains
"13579ÿ". How can I remove this ÿ? Why does this happen?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define true 1

int main(void){

    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r+");
    FILE *odd = fopen("odd.txt", "w");
    FILE *even = fopen("even.txt", "w");
    
    char ch;
    while(true){
        ch = fgetc(fp); 

        if((ch - '0') % 2 == 0){//even
            fputc(ch, even);
        }
        else{//odd
            fputc(ch, odd);
        }

        if(feof(fp)){
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(odd);
    fclose(even);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `feof` tests whether the _previous_ read operation succeeded, not whether there is still data available.

Comment: You need to declare `ch` as `int`, and test it for `EOF`.  And then you don't need `feof` at all.

Comment: mehmet emre topdal, had the file contained 0 characters, what do you expect would have been printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is caused by sending `EOF` (aka -1) to `odd`. This EOF sentinel is received by `fgetc()` when encountering an end of input file.

Check if a digit was actually parsed

```
   if('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') {
        if ((ch - '0') % 2 == 0) {
            fputc(ch, even);
        }
        else{//odd
            fputc(ch, odd);
        }
   } else {
        ... error
   }
```

Moreover, check `feof()` **before** processing `ch`, or change type of `ch` to `int` to let it contain `EOF` value.
You could use `isdigit()` defined in `<ctype.h>`.

The loop could look like this:

```
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if(isdigit(ch)) {
            if ((ch - '0') % 2 == 0) {
                fputc(ch, even);
            } else { //odd
                fputc(ch, odd);
            }
        } else {
            ... error ?
        }
    }
```

Comment: "check feof() before processing ch " i tried this and it worked. Thank you everyone

Comment: For one less test in the loop, could use `while (isdigit(ch = fgetc(fp))) { ... } if (ch != EOF) Error()`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I'm not sure, it will stop on the first non-digit like i.e. whitespace. It may not be what was indented.